# Unable to remove Escape sequences using Regex.Unescape in C#

Tags: c#, regex, .net-core, escaping, unescapestring

I want to remove all the escape sequences from the below string which I get from Pokemon API.

"A strange seed was\nplanted on its\nback at birth.\fThe plant sprouts\nand grows with\nthis POKéMON."

I have used `Regex.Unescape("A strange seed was\nplanted on its\nback at birth.\fThe plant sprouts\nand grows with\nthis POKéMON.")` but I am getting the same string.

Output  [image]

Could you please help me to sort this out?

I do not want to do a string replace as escaping sequence might be different in the next API call.

Comment: Your original string doesn't contain any escaped characters. It contains newline characters, which are escaped in the *string literal* as `\n`, and then escaped *by the debugger*. But the string doesn't actually contain any backslashes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. this line break actually breaks my Uri.EscapeUriString(). Basically, I need to send this string to https://funtranslations.com/api/shakespeare#translate as a query string parameter.
Uri.EscapeUriString(<mystring>). I get below result A%20strange%20seed%20was%0Aplanted%20on%20its%0Aback%20at%20birth.%0CThe%20plant%20sprouts%0Aand%20grows%20with%0Athis%20POK%C3%A9MON.

Unfortunately I get an error with this. If I remove the \n and \f before uri encoding, then I was able to get the result what I want.

Comment: Right, so remove those... but don't expect an Unescape method to do anything when you have no escape sequences. (You wouldn't want to unescape them anyway by the sounds of it - it sounds like you want to *remove* the characters, which isn't the same thing.)

Comment: _"I get below result"_ - What's wrong with that? What result do you expect?

Comment: ah ok, is it that means I have to manually remove all of them using string.Replace()?

Comment: Yes, if you want to remove those characters you'll have to replace them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you're getting the same string - there are no escaped characters in your example :)

The string *literal* has escape characters, but those aren't present in the string itself. When the immediate window does the printout of the result, it shows it as a string literal itself. It's not the same you would get from something like `Console.WriteLine`, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. this line actually breaks my Uri.EscapeUriString(). Basically, I need to send this string to funtranslations.com/api/shakespeare#translate as a query string parameter. Uri.EscapeUriString(<mystring>). I get below result A%20strange%20seed%20was%0Aplanted%20on%20its%0Aback%20at%20birth.%0CThe%20plant%20sprouts%0Aand%20grows%20with%0Athis%20POK%C3%A9MON. Unfortunately I get an error with this. If I remove the \n and \f before uri encoding, then I was able to get the result that I want.

Comment: https://api.funtranslations.com/translate/shakespeare.json?text=A%20strange%20seed%20was%0Aplanted%20on%20its%0Aback%20at%20birth.%0CThe%20plant%20sprouts%0Aand%20grows%20with%0Athis%20POK%C3%A9MON.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [regex replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-5.0) and have a set of possible escape sequences (like \n and \t etc)

[image: regex example]

(updated) example: https://rextester.com/WXSC17170

Comment: This regex won't match anything. [Example](https://rextester.com/ZQIY6170)

Comment: Remove the @ from example and display result, it should work then:
https://rextester.com/ZSVQ23438